# Ranking within Django ORM or SQL?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-orm

**I have a huge list ranked by various values** (eg. scores)

So I grab the list ordered by these values:

```
players = Player.objects.order_by('-score', '-karma')
```

---

I would like to:

- Grab a player and get the **neighbouring players**

> P1 score:123
>
> P2 score:122
>
> **YOU**! score:**110**
>
> P3 score:90
>
> P2 score:89

- Grab the **position**!

> You are ranked #1234 for score
>
> You are ranked #9876 for karma

---

Help would be very much appreciated. thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the ranking of the user:

```
(SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Score desc ,Karma desc) AS ranking,
    Id,
    Username,
    Score, karma
  FROM Players 
) AS players_ranked_by_score
where Id = id_of_user
```

Where id_of_user is the parameter containing the id of the current player. To get the neighboring players **and** the current user:

```
(SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Score desc ,Karma desc) AS ranking,
    Id,
    Username,
    Score, karma
  FROM Players 
) AS all_players_ranked
where ranking >= player_ranking - 2 and ranking <= player_ranking + 2;
```

Where player_ranking is the ranking obtained from the query above.

Hope it helps!

**Update**: MySQL does not have a rank() function (MS SQL, Oracle, Postgres have one). I looked around and I got this link explaining how to do ranking in MySQL: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1024#460.

Comment: `RANK()` appears to be a SQL Server specific extension. It's not available in most SQL dialects.

Comment: Thanks awesome reply! Btw @Daniel can't find RANK() in MySQL reference, would you say MySQL dialect supports this?

Comment: It's not just SQL Server; Postgres 8.4 includes RANK() as well. Don't know about MySQL; I think at least it has something similar.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know MySql did not have it.  I know SQL Server, Oracle and Postgres have a rank function. I was looking around for a rank function for MySql and I got this link:

http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1024#460

Comment: Wow thanks Juan! That's a useful link! Can you add it to your answer?

Answer (score 9):

These sorts of things are always very difficult to do. You'll need multiple queries for each one.

So, to get the players just before and after your position when ordered by score, first you'll need to work out what that position is. (Note that this assumes that you can't have more than one person with the same score, which may not necessarily be true.)

```
me = Player.objects.get(pk=my_pk)
position = Players.objects.all().filter(
                            score__lte=me.score).order_by('-score').count()

players = Players.objects.all()[position-2:position+2]
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. This is a very helpful reply!

Comment: - you don't need all(), just apply the filter
- score__lt works better for ranking (equal score -> equal rank)
- in last part, result is not ordered, so the position wouldn't help, you should order it first
- if position < 2, there will be exception, you should clamp the minimum of position-2 to 0 (the high part is ok)

Answer (score 0):

I did this with 3 queries with ORM, but I think less count of queries would be better:

```
user_rank = Score.objects.filter(high_score__gt=user_score.high_score).count() + 1

neighbour_scores = Score.objects.filter(game_id=gme,~Q(user_id = usr),high_score__gte=user_score.high_score).order_by('high_score')[:offset]
neighbour_scores.append(user_score)
neighbour_scores.append(Score.objects.filter(game_id=gme, high_score__lt=user_score.high_score).order_by('-high_score')[:offset])
```