# Django window function to partition over a subquery

Tags: django, django-models

So, given I have a table in django:

```py
class A(models.Model):
    a: models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

I want to replicate this SQL using django's ORM:

```sql
SELECT "id"
FROM (
        SELECT id, a
        FROM a_a
        LIMIT 100000
    ) inner
ORDER BY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a);
```

The window function part I get, but I'm unable to figure out how to partition over a subquery in django, which I need for applying the limit.

*Edit*:

To be clear, I *know* how to do this without the `LIMIT 1000`, and the subquery. I'm particularly asking about the limit, because my data is too large to compute the rank over the whole table, and that particular use case is fine with incomplete data (the user would later refine their query, in which case the limit is non-consequential). The limit is there to limit the worst-case cost of the query.

I'm also aware of raw queries, which is what I'm using now.

But, I guess, what I want is not possible with Django, and, because it's a rather rare case, probably not worth it anyway.

Comment: might help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141978/ranking-within-django-orm-or-sql

Comment: Yes, it's similar, but the provided solution is also "just" in sql. I'm asking if it's possible in django.

Comment: As a last resort you can try raw query, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120467/order-queryset-by-alternating-value, check @T.Tokic answer

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I'm using raw queries now, which works, but isn't as nice. Also, yes, that example does something similar, but the inner limit is missing.